# Debugger Pane does not open in Atom using Julia

Tags: julia

When I click:  "Juno- Open Debugger Pane" nothing happens. I thought that this would trigger the Debugger Pane to open so I can try and run my code with a breakpoint to do some Debugging.

I am able to open the "Plots Pane" but the Debugger does not seem to open. I also tried restarting Atom but the issue persisted. Here is my debug info:

```
# Atom:
Version: 1.45.0
Dev Mode: false
Official Release: true
{
  "http_parser": "2.8.0",
  "node": "10.11.0",
  "v8": "6.9.427.31-electron.0",
  "uv": "1.23.0",
  "zlib": "1.2.11",
  "ares": "1.14.0",
  "modules": "69",
  "nghttp2": "1.33.0",
  "napi": "3",
  "openssl": "1.1.0",
  "electron": "4.2.7",
  "chrome": "69.0.3497.128",
  "icu": "62.2",
  "unicode": "11.0",
  "cldr": "33.1",
  "tz": "2019a"
}
# julia-client:
Version: 0.11.3
Config:
{
  "firstBoot": false,
  "juliaPath": "/Applications/Julia-1.3.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia",
  "uiOptions": {
    "enableMenu": true,
    "enableToolBar": true
  }
}


# ink:
Version: 0.11.8
Config:
undefined


# uber-juno:
Version: 0.3.0
Config:
{
  "disable": true
}


# language-julia:
Version: 0.19.2
Config:
undefined


# language-weave:not installed


# indent-detective:
Version: 0.4.0
Config:
undefined


# latex-completions:
Version: 0.3.6
Config:
undefined


# versioninfo():
Julia Version 1.3.0
Commit 46ce4d7933 (2019-11-26 06:09 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: macOS (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6267U CPU @ 2.90GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-6.0.1 (ORCJIT, skylake)
Environment:
  JULIA_EDITOR = atom  -a
  JULIA_NUM_THREADS = 2
```

Comment: I'd recommend upgrading to Juno 0.12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When something does not work with Atom Juno there are always three possible issues.

1. Your support for Atom and Juno in Julia is outdated. Try upgrading packages

```
using Pkg
pkg"update Atom"
pkg"update Juno"
```

2. Now check if Juno installation within Atom is up-to date - if not upgrade it
3. Sometimes after step (2) Juno stops working in Atom (there is no Julia menu) or is working partially. If that happens go to your home folder (e.g. `c:\users\yourname` in Windows) and delete a folder named `.atom`. Once the folder is deleted, launch Atom and install again Juno.

For me those three steps always work.